# Where do I ask a question which is related to both travel and money?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have this question:

> A conference where I am invited to, as a speaker, asks to select
>   either one of the following 2 options for money transfer:
>
> 1. Direct deposit in USD
> 2. Wire transfer.
>
> The conference is happening in London UK. But, if selected the wire
>   transfer, they shall be wiring from the USA.
>
> So, which option would be beneficial for me (Indian citizen),
>   considering the conversion for direct deposit and the wire transfer
>   commission cuts[if any]?

I am confused between Travel SE and Money SE. Where would this question be more appropriate?

Comment: I fail to see how this question has anything to do with travel at all.  The question is exactly the same even if you're never leaving your home, so the traveling you're doing has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Servy Makes sense :)  The fact that it's a UK conf. and the money paid is in USD, I thought the folks at travel SE would know better about the conversion hacks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Servy's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299765/where-do-i-ask-a-question-which-is-related-to-both-travel-and-money#comment974215_299765), I thought it would be a better fit in Money SE rather than in Travel SE, as it is more related to a money transaction rather than a travel/traveler's query. So, I have posted the question [there](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/83991/32662).

A question like **What would be the best way to exchange money from USD to INR in London** would be more on-topic in Travel SE.